# Need to add callback function if the action suceeds. Its not working (react native and redux)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have uploaded an array data to the server using axios. But after the upload completes (ie. if it succeeds), I want to empty an array or add some elements to the array. Everthing works but after it succeeds how can I do smth to the array, it is not working in the following code. Thankyou.

code:

```
var testArray = [];

uploadData = () => {
    this.props.uploadataToServer(testArray);

    if (this.props.uploadStatus == true) { //this code is not working
        testArray = [];
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.uploadData()}>
                <Text>Upload data</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { uploadStatus } = state.Upload;
    return { uploadStatus };
}
```

action:

```
export const uploadataToServer = (testArray) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios({
            url: testUrl,
            data: {
                upladArray: testArray
            }
        }).then(response => {
            if(response.data.status == true) {
                dispatch({
                    type: UPLOAD_TO_SERVER,
                    dataStatus: response.data.status,
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

reducer:

```
switch(actions) {
    case UPLOAD_TO_SERVER:
        return { uploadStatus: actions.dataStatus}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check in **componentDidUpdate** as you will receive updated props at that time

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.uploadStatus !== this.props.uploadStatus) {
    if (this.props.uploadStatus == true) {
        testArray = [];
    }
  }
}
```